# How to rename namespaced fabric commands

Tags: python, fabric

How do you control how custom Fabric commands are exposed?

I organize my commands in various packages like:

```
mydomain
    __init__.py
    db.py
        @task
        def create()...

        @task()
        def dump()...

        @task
        def shell()...
```

And when I run `fab --list`, I see Fabric exposes my commands prefixed with `mydomain`:

```
mydomain.db.create
mydomain.db.dump
mydomain.db.shell
```

How do I get Fabric to drop the `mydomain` prefix, while still keeping the tasks organized in my custom namespace? I've tried specifying name in `@task(name=...)`, but that has no effect on the namespace.

Comment: Are you importing the commands from another module into your fabfile, or did you mess around with the main() function? Those are the two instances this has occurred for me

Answer (score 1):

I have the following structure which does not prefix with the package name.

```
fab --version
Fabric 1.8.0
Paramiko 1.12.0

rootdir/
     fabfile.py
     mydomain/
             __init__.py
             db.py
             other.py
```

## fabfile.py

```
from fabric.api import task
from mydomain import db, other

@task
def boom():
    print "boom"
```

## db.py

```
from fabric.api import task

@task
def create():
    print "create"

@task()
def dump():
    print "dump"
```

## other.py

```
from fabric.api import task

@task
def do_stuff():
    print "doing stuff"
```

## fab --list output

```
fab --list
Available commands:

    boom
    db.create
    db.dump
    other.do_stuff
```

I notice that if I import with

```
import mydomain.db
import mydomain.other
```

then the output is:

```
fab --list
Available commands:

    boom
    mydomain.db.create
    mydomain.db.dump
    mydomain.other.do_stuff
```

So take a look at how your are importing your packages, that seems to be what causes it